# How does the following lines of code work in PHP?

Tags: php

So I have a couple of examples with sums in PHP and they are as following:

```
$var = "0"; // $var = "0" string
$var++; // $var = "1"
$var+=1; // $var = 2 integer
$var += ‘c’; // $var = 2 integer
$var = $var + 1.3; // $var = 3.3 float
$var = 5 + "10 obiecte"; // $var =15
$var = 5 + "obiecte"; // $var =5 integer
```

But I do not understand the following one: $var = 5 + "10 obiecte"; // $var =15, why is this sum equal to 15? Does PHP takes the integer out of the string and adds it to 5? Is this somehow similar to Python? If there was something like $var = 5 + "1object0", what will the sum be like?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: If a string starts with a number then what is invalid for an integer/float is just truncated, otherwise it is 0.

Comment: oh so it HAS to start with the integer/float, if it's a string and then an integer at the end, everything will me 0, right?

Comment: @AbraCadaver maybe I need to tag you to see:))

Comment: Yes use the link I posted to click on other links to see how things are converted https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.numeric-strings.php

Comment: Could you please make your title more specific? E.g. 'How does PHP deal with string to number conversion?' I'm sure you can come up with something better,